# untar file with same name every time new file uploaded via ftp

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, tar

i am using zoneminder on Raspberry pi 3 for motion detection using ip camera.
zoneminder has ftp upload file option. now the problem is that the zoneminder is uploading tar files to server directory , now i want a program/script that continuously check directory and untar every updated file with same name.

file name is like:

ipcam-2044.tar next file will be ipcam-2045.tar

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood this script should be the one you 're looking for:
it just extract all tar files and delete the source archive

```
 for file in *.tar; do tar xf "${file}" && rm "${file}"; done
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing here.

Comment: @mauromuro will it run continuously? because tar files are uploaded continuously through the day